# What things are not saved in a btrfs snapshot?

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, root-filesystem, snapshot, snapper

I'm using BTRFS for my root partition and manage its snapshots with Snapper. I decided to create subvolumes for `/var/tmp`, `/var/cache` and `/var/log` as these are constantly changing its data which is not a good idea for scheduled snapshotting. In this way, they are not saved.

However, I noticed that files inside `/tmp` where included in the snapshots too, which is not what I want. I was mounting a tmpfs filesystem there but it was saved anyways. I ended up creating a subvolume for it.

I noticed that `/sys`, `/run` and `/proc` are not saved (which is a good thing). What do they do to achieve that? can I do the same for `/tmp`? what things are not saved in a btrfs snapshot? besides other subvolumes, of course.

Comment: What makes you think /tmp was saved in the snapshot? Are you sure there weren't files already in the directory before it mounted the tmpfs? Those would be hidden when the tmpfs is mounted and would be included in the snapshot. If it's actually mounted as a tmpfs there is no way it could be included in a normal btrfs snapshot, it's a totally different filesystem.

Comment: Mount your btrfs somewhere *as a whole* (`subvol=/`, compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1396270)). Navigate to the subvolume that is the root of your OS, then to `tmp`. Here you see how your `/tmp` looks before anything else (like tmpfs) gets mounted over it. If it's not a subvolume and it's not empty, then the files belong to the subvolume that is the root of your OS. Probably you don't need these files. From your description I conclude that `sys`, `run` and `proc` next to this `tmp` are empty. You can verify this. If `sys` is empty and `tmp` is not, then this is the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kamil Maciorowski's comment, I realized that I had to clean /tmp before mounting the tmpfs. Now snapshots have an empty /tmp. My mistake was to think that /tmp was cleaned when powering off.